# Seeking for a formula for integrating polynomials on unit cube with linear constraint

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, definite-integrals

I am seeking for a closed-form formula for integration of polynomial on unit cube with linear constraint as follows:

I want to evaluate $\int _{x\in[0,1]^n,\\ \sum_i x_i=1}p(x)dx$ where $p(x):\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is a polynomial.

**My efforts so far:**

First, to get a general formula, it is sufficient to show a formula for $\int _{x\in[0,1]^n,\\ \sum_i x_i=1}\prod_i x_i^{a_i}dx$ for $\{a_i\}_i\subset\mathbb N$.

I first tried to study the special case $p(x)=\prod_i x_i$, so for $n=2$ we get: $\int_{0\leq x,y\leq 1,\\ x+y=1} (xy)dxdy=\int_0^1 x(1-x) dx$ which is easy to evaluate.

However, in higher dimensions it becomes more complicated, as $\int_{0\leq x,y,z\leq 1,\\ x+y+z=1} (xyz)dxdydz\lneq\int_0^1\int_0^1 xy(1-x-y) dx$, and I don't know how to evaluate the latter one.

So, I am stuck here, and your help would be highly appreciated.